# Couldn't load plugin class: com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter Cucumber 5.4.2

Tags: cucumber, extentreports

I'm trying to use ExtentReport plugin with Cucumber 5+ but most tutorials I see so far are for either Cucumber 4 or the old info.cukes dependency, which I'm no longer able to use due to conflicts with other parts of my application.

These are the dependencies I have on my pom file and my MainRunner if anyone can please point out what I may be missing?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

MainRunner

```
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import selenium_demo.managers.FileReaderManager;

import java.io.File;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"."},
        glue = {"selenium_demo.steps", "selenium_demo.hooks"},
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
)

public class MainRunner {

    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getReportConfigPath()));
    }
}
```

Sample for the issue can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/francislainy-campos/seleniumdemo/src/extent_report_issue/src/test/java/selenium_demo/)

Thank you.

Comment: At this moment it seems Cucumber 5 is not supported. Changed it to Cluecumber instead but will leave the question open in case extents report start working again under a new update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658416/how-to-use-cluecumber-to-generate-reports