# How to use Cluecumber to generate reports?

Tags: automation, cucumber, report

How to generate reports for automation tests using [Cluecumber](https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin)?

Comment: While this may be good reference material (I don't know the tech), I would suggest you update your question to be more specific. When self answering, it's important to still ask the question as if you are not the one who will be answering it. This helps seekers find the question, and know it relates to them, which puts more emphasis on the correct answer

Comment: Thanks @Sterling. It's updated now if the downvote can be removed as the tech is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add the Cluecumber plugin to your pom file. As of the time of this writing the most recent version is 2.3.4 but this can be checked [here](https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin/releases) for updates.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
           <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.4</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>report</id>
                   <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>reporting</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
         <configuration>
               <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
               <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-report
               </generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```
2. Add `json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json` to your `Runner`, so you would have something like this:

   ```
   import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
   import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @CucumberOptions(
       features = {"."},
       glue = {"my_folder.steps", "my_folder.hooks"},
       monochrome = true,
       plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json"}
   )

   public class MainRunner {

   }
   ```

*PS: No need for html target*

3. Run your tests and once this is done navigate to the terminal and type `mvn cluecumber-report:reporting` (exactly as it is).

This will generate a folder that only appears when this command is run. It'll be under `target` folder and will be called `generated-report`. There you should find the `index.html` file where your reports should be (right click and open it on a browser to see it).

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to keep this reports with a name different than index.html or adding a date after the file?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the file name as the file is auto generated every time you type the maven command on the terminal. index.html is usually the default for html pages and I wouldn't try and change that myself to be honest. But I think it may be possible to customise the content a bit, just never tried that myself so you may need to go after some tutorials on the internet as they may exist.

Comment: Hi Francislainy: Is it possible to add the command mvn cluecumber-report:reporting in the POM for generating the reports without running that in Command line?

Comment: Sorry, dont know any other way to run it without the maven command, but if you're on IntelliJ you could create a run configuration for a maven template and paste the command there (without the mvn word) and then every time you'd need the report you'd need just to click run on that configuration rather than typing the whole thing.